# Bash script- Displaying a decimal variable in an emal

Tags: bash

So, I want to send mail to someone using this command

```
mail -s "subject" email@email.com <<< "the value is "$b" and it is a decimal"
```

In this case $b has the value of 7.5, so it wont display. Any ways to show the value in the message?

Comment: What shell are you using? bash or "/bin/sh"? If bash, aside from the quoting error, that should work OK. Replace the mail command with `cat`, and what do you see?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by piping & escaping correctly:

```
echo "the value is \"$b\" and it is a decimal" | mail -s "subject" email@email.com
```